# simplehtmldom parsing script to break the data coming in plain text

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Here is my script in which I am fetching three items **Medicine Name, Generic Name, Class Name**. My problem here is that I am successful in fetching the **Medicine name** separately but the **Generic Name and Class Name** is coming as string. If you will run the script you will get better idea what I am actually trying to say, I want to store **Generic Name and Class Name** is separate columns in table.

**Script**

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

//simple html dom file
require('simple_html_dom.php');

//target url
$html = file_get_html('http://www.drugs.com/condition/atrial-flutter.html?rest=1');

//crawl td columns

 foreach($html->find('td') as $element)
{   
    //get drug name
    $drug_name = $element->find('b');
    foreach($drug_name as $drug_name)
    {
        echo "Drug Name:-".$drug_name;

        foreach($element->find('span[class=small] a',2) as $t)
        {
            //get the inner HTML
            $data = $t->plaintext;
            echo $data;
        }

        echo "<br/>";
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is a little bit far from what you need to do but you could utilize css selectors to get those elements easier.

Example:

```
$data = array();
$html = file_get_html('http://www.drugs.com/condition/atrial-flutter.html?rest=1');
foreach($html->find('tr td[1]') as $td) { // you do not need to loop each td!
// target the first td of the row
    $drug_name = $td->find('a b', 0)->innertext; // get the drug name bold tag inside anchor
    $other_info = $td->find('span.small[2]', 0); // get the other info
    $generic_name = $other_info->find('a[1]', 0)->innertext; // get the first anchor, generic name
    $children_count = count($other_info->children()); // count all of the children
    $classes = array();
    for($i = 1; $i < $children_count; $i++) { // since you already got the first, (in position zero) iterate all children starting from 1
        $classes[] = $other_info->find('a', $i)->innertext; // push it inside another container
    }

    $data[] = array(
        'drug_name' => $drug_name,
        'generic_name' => $generic_name,
        'classes' => $classes,
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: @user2960749: If a proposed solution helped you, you should *accept* it. Simply click the little tick below the post score.